# Is there a difference between using a network share address vs a local address for a folder?

Tags: windows-10, networking, file-permissions, shared-folders

I recently ran into a problem where a Computer A could not pull files from a shared folder on Computer B unless the files were put into the shared folder on Computer B via the network share path. Checking the file permissions (as the folder permissions are set correctly), it looks like not all of the folder permissions are put down when using the C:\ directory. However when you use the shared address, all of the folder permissions are copied to the file. When I spoke to the developer in charge of the program that was writing the files into the folder, they said that they are aware of the problem but not currently looking into fixing it as there is a workaround.

Does anyone have any insight into why this might be happening? I agree it seems like a permissions issue but it's strange that the network share address is giving more permissions than the C:\ address. I would think the opposite would be true.

Any input or reading anyone has on this would be really helpful. I'm a bit stumped as to why this could be happening.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing through the network, you need to present credentials to the
target computers. These credentials are translated to a user account on the
target computer.

When directly accessing the folder, a program uses the user account it is
running under.

From your description, the two accounts are not the same, so the resulting
file permissions are not the same.

You might be able to workaround this problem by changing the account under
which is running this program, to one that plays better with the accessing
account over the network. Or give the network account more permissions,
as required.

(I can't go here beyond general advice, as I don't know enough regarding your
setup.)

Comment: Gotcha, I kept the description fairly general as I wasn't sure. The way the program works is it runs as a service to make sure it is always running whenever the computer is on. When logging in as a user on the computer, you can access the application via a URL on the desktop. 

Would the file permissions change then based on if the "Service" put things in at the local level (C:\) vs the network share? I guess I'm just a bit confused as to why the service would have different (and better) permissions on the network level.

Comment: A system service runs either under a user account or under NETWORK SERVICE (which is basically part of Windows and has all permissions). Choosing another account for the service might solve the problem (or not?).